# Rails hide Model field by default to every query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-models

I hava users table and it has a field password_digest and I am working with an API and I want to appply this:

```
Users.all.select(*User.attribute_names.reject { |attr| attr == 'password_digest' })
```

but I have to write this in every query I do, how can I set this as a default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **default scope**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope select(*User.attribute_names.reject { |attr| attr == 'password_digest' })
end
```

**Another way :**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope select(User.column_names - ["password_digest"])
end
```

**Reference:**
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

Comment: It works, thank you I only had to write it like this: 
`default_scope { select(*User.attribute_names.reject { |attr| attr == 'password_digest' }) }`